# Easy way to transform typescript into js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, jsx

Is there any way to remove typescript-specific keywords from a js(x) file, while making sure it is still human readable, and still preserving JSX specific syntax (ie, not `tsc`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can configure [`jsx`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#jsx) in your `tsconfig.json` to `preserve` *(and apparently `react-native`?)* to keep the JSX tags intact. That *shouldn't* touch readability, assuming it isn't configured to e.g. convert ESM import syntax to CJS require syntax.

You can also import `typescript` as a module and use their compiler API to directly transpile your TS code without any type checking, if that's what you want.